# How to rebind mouse buttons?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

is it possible to rebind the mouse buttons in Neverwinter Nights?

I can't change them through the Options interface in-game. I would like to know if there is a hack or something to do it.

Comment: Are you using a Razer mouse by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I would like to set the left button as camera movement and button 4 as radial menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Razer Synapse software you can remap keys.

[I wrote a blog post](http://blog.k1dblitz.com/2013/01/transformers-fall-of-cybertron-tweaks.html) on how to do this with a Razer keyboard, but the process is similar with a Razer mouse.

I recommend creating a new profile and then linking that profile to the Neverwinter executable. This will make the Synapse software automagically switch profiles for you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfornately, Razer Synapse did not work for my mouse (I think it's old), but I could download the Razer Lachesis driver itself and I'm able to change through it. So your answer gave me a clue :).